# vendor.camera.aux.packagelist in capacitorjs app

Tags: android, phonegap, capacitor

I am building a QR code reader in VueJS, Capacitor using the PhonegapBarcodePlugin.

In iPhone it works perfectly.

In android I get:

```
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
W/myApp: type=1400 audit(0.0:5658): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:persist_camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=21599 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c19,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:persist_camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

All of these exist in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
W/cr_MediaCodecUtil: HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.

Comment: and it works on Samsung Note8 (android 9), not on Nokia 7 (android 10)

Comment: It seems the issue may be related to a recent security patch sicne the code still works on older samsung devices.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain it, but it must have been some setting in the phone itself. I reset camera settings and the problem disappeared. I wish I knew what setting it was, or what caused it.

I had this issue in:
Cordova
Ionic Capacitor
and a few native apps, and after resetting disappeared.

For now, I am assuming the security patch changed a global setting, and resetting my settings to default removed that